# Due to TIME stopping, are contemporary Black Holes really just Large SHELLS of Matter and not Singularities?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, singularities

If TIME slows down as you approach a Black Hole, has there been sufficient time in our Universe (13.8 Billion Years since the Big Bang occurred) for ANY matter inside the Event Horizon of ANY Black Hole to reach the "center" - or form a singularity ?
In the given age of our Universe (13.8 Billion Years) would not all Black Holes be huge (rotating) spherical SHELLS where the in-falling Matter accumulates and gets compressed just inside of the Event Horizon and , in it's very slow time frame, has not had sufficient **time** to traverse the space toward the supposed central SINGULARITY ?
This might obviate the actual existence of "Singularities".
That is, there may not been **sufficient elapsed TIME** (in 13.8 Billion of our years) for any singularity to have actually formed in OUR 'normal time' universe.
It might be that our Universe is too young to have had enough time (inside the Black Holes) for a true 'singularity' to have formed....it may be an ongoing process and takes maybe Trillions of years to accomplish.

Comment: Tangentially, anyone recall what the newest age estimate is since the variable-expansion thingie?

Comment: 13.8 billion years.

Comment: Matter and radiation have no problem crossing the event horizon. *You* have a problem seeing them do it, but the black hole doesn’t care about that.

Comment: Your question is based on invalid assumptions, because the age of the universe is irrelevant. Nothing can cross the event horizon ever. In fact, no true horizon can ever form, but the apparent horizon that does form has nearly the same properties, except there is nothing inside it. Unfortunately there is a wide spread confusion on this subject, so you'll hear a lot of opinions here that matter can cross the horizon. This is incorrect, because the infalling observer dies not have a frame of reference at the horizon while in any other frame he never crosses over.